# Convergence of a series of bounded linear operators to zero.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory

I'm working on a proof and I have a term I can't seem to handle. The problem at hand can be isolated to the following: Let $(T_n)$ be a sequence of bounded linear operators that are uniformly  operator convergent to $T$. Also all terms in the sequence have the same spectrum, and are less than $1$.

Show that there exits an $N_{\epsilon}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\left\lVert T_{m}T_{m-1}\cdots T_{m+1-i} -T_{n}T_{n-1}\cdots T_{n+1-i}\right\rVert<\epsilon$ when $m>n\ge N_{\epsilon}$

I assume I need to rely on the operator convergence of $(T_n), (T_nT_{n-1})$ etc. and the facts that $\left\lVert T_j\cdots T_i\right\rVert\to 0$ as $\left|j-i+1\right|\to \infty$. But can't seem to piece it together.

Not sure it is actually true, any help would greatly be appreciated. Even a possible direction to investigate would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space and $T_n = \sum_{i=1}^n |e_i> <e_i|$. Then the $T_n \le \mathbb{1}$ and the spectrum of $T_n$ is $\{0,1\}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $T_n$ converges to $\mathbb{1}$.
Now, let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m = n+1$ we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} \| T_m \cdots T_{m+1-i} - T_n \cdots T_{n+1-i} \| \ge \| T_m - T_n \| = \| |e_{n+1}>< e_{n+1}|\| = 1.
\end{align*}
So there exists no $N_{\varepsilon}$ with the desired property.

Comment: Hi, in my post I should have said uniformly  convergent, not strongly, so I've fixed that. In your example $T_n$ converges to the identity operator, but that means the spectrum is changing? In my qeustion it's is constant. Can you elaborate as to what $e_{n+1}><e_{n+1}$ means, as I'm unfamiliar with the notation. Thanks :)

Comment: $|e_n><e_n|$ means the projection on the $n$ basis vector. And indeed, the spectrum of the identity operator is different, but the spectrum of the sequence is constant. If you want that also $T$ has the same spectrum, the same sequence will do, if we start the basis of $\mathcal{H}$ with $e_0$, so that $T_n$ converges to $\mathbb{1} - |e_0><e_0|$, which also has spectrum $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Do think my original statement is true in a finite dimensional space?

Comment: In a finite dimensional space, the strong and norm topology are the same, so in that case it depends on whether your new question is true or not.